# When does Yii:autoload($className) invoked?

Tags: php, yii, autoload

I'm looking for `__autoload` magic method inside the `YiiBase` class, but it isn't. In the official docs said that `public static function autoload($className)` is

> Class autoload loader. This method is provided to be invoked within an
>   __autoload() magic method.

I'm confused. What class of `yii` framework contains `__autoload` magic method? Is it possible to get an example with a component class autoloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii uses the [`spl_autoload_register`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) function to set the autoloader function. The `spl_autoload_register` was introduced in PHP 5.1.2 and makes it possible for us to register multiple autoload functions. It effectively creates a queue of autoload functions, and runs through each of them in the order they are defined. By contrast, `__autoload()` may only be defined once. In Yii you can find this in `YiiBase.php`, just after the definition of the `YiiBase` class, at the very end of the file:

```
spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
```

Where `autoload` is a static method definied in the `YiiBase` class.

Using `spl_autoload_register` instead of the `__autoload()` magic function is good for us, because this way Yii's autoloader does not conflict with our own or with another thrid-party's autoloader. The `YiiBase` class also defines a [`registerAutoloader`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/YiiBase#registerAutoloader-detail) function to register another autoloader function before or after Yii's autoloader in the chain. If you take a look at its code, it is pretty straightforward what it does:

```
public static function registerAutoloader($callback, $append=false)
{
    if($append)
    {
        self::$enableIncludePath=false;
        spl_autoload_register($callback);
    }
    else
    {
        spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
        spl_autoload_register($callback);
        spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
    }
}
```

It really just uses `spl_autoload_register` and/or `spl_autoload_unregister` (yes, you can also unregister an autoload function!), to put the new autoloader before or after Yii's autoloader, because `spl_autoload_register` always registers the new autoloader at the end of the chain.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Yii tries to autoload a class whenever you reference it. Yii is simply making use of PHP's `__autoload()` function. It's a magic method like `__get()` or `__set()`.

For example, when you write `$foo = new Foo();` and class `Foo` has not been loaded yet, you will get an Error.

But you can prevent that if you define an `__autoload($classname)` function before. This way, instead of throwing an Error, PHP will first try to run the `__autoload($classname)` function. In that function, you can do things like: include the variable `$classname` and so on.

There's more information here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php